# Continuous test-driven development for Rust

Tags: tdd, rust

Ruby has [Autotest](https://github.com/grosser/autotest), JavaScript has [Wallabyjs](http://wallabyjs.com/), both run test and present the results automatically on every save.

Is there any [Continuous test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_test-driven_development) system available for rust?

Otherwise, what is the reason for the absence? Is there a technical reason, why such a system makes no sense with rust, or did simply no one care about writing one, yet?

Comment: Quick note: wallaby.js doesn't actually need you to save files, it runs tests as you type code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`cargo-watch`](https://github.com/passcod/cargo-watch).

1. Install it by running `$ cargo install cargo-watch`
2. In your project directory run `$ cargo watch` (or `$ cargo watch test` to be specific)

---

However, there are some differences to JS and Ruby: Rust is a compiled language and the compilation step takes some time. So you cannot expect immediate feedback, like you get from interpreted languages.